# Opencart/JQuery - identifying which banner was clicked - can this be improved

Tags: jquery, opencart

Two issues:

Opencart shows its banners as items within an owl-wrapper container. It also creates cached copies of banners, which are resized and renamed to reflect the size they were rendered at.

```
<div class="owl-wrapper" >
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/product1">
                <img src="http://website.com/image/cache/catalog/ads/ad1-sample-1920x735.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/product2">
                <img src="http://website.com/image/cache/catalog/ads/ad2-sample-1920x735.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/product3">
                <img src="http://website.com/image/cache/catalog/ads/ad3-sample-1920x735.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ad3-sample.jpg gets resized and renamed to ad3-sample-1920x735.jpg

I'm wanting to log banner clicks, so i have a jquery script that goes roughly as follows:

```
    $('.owl-wrapper .owl-item .item a[href]').bind('click', function() {
        var banner_src  = $(this).children("img").attr("src");

        var banner_img = banner_src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

        var src_image =  banner_img.replace(/\b-[0-9]*[x][0-9]*./g, '.');

        // do stuff here
    });
```

First, we get the filename of the image that was clicked on, then we remove the path data from the string, and lastly remove the `-widthxheight` from the string.

It works properly, but wondering if anyone could foresee an issue? Like, rather than parsing the img src, would i be better served by adding the `banner_image_id` to the output and selecting that instead?

Also, even though the images and links are generally nested within several divs:

```
 $('.owl-wrapper .owl-item .item a[href]')
```

Could just as easily be:

```
 $('.owl-wrapper a[href]')
```

So really, I think things are working properly, but wanted to ask for feedback as I'm sure there are people here who have done this before, if not with opencart then with jQuery in general.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated you should use `.on()` or directly `.click()`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that!